# фильтр файлов по имени и дате при помощи регулярных выражений

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, потоки-данных

Добрый день! Задача: "Из массива файлов выбрать файлы с определенным текстом и датой в имени файла(между ними еще текст) ". Пытаюсь с помощью регулярных выражений решить задачу.

```java
List fileNames=Arrays.stream(files).filter(p>Pattern.compile("Реестр сделок("+date.toString("dd.MM.yyyy")+")").matches(p.getName()).collect;
```

Comment: А что не получается?

Comment: не получается синтаксически верно написать условие фильтра с помощью регулярки по 2 критериям: "Реестр сделок" и "date". Новичок:) прошу помощи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае регулярное выражение для имени файла, в котором имеются слова "реестр сделок" и определённая дата будет следующим:

```
^.*реестр\s+сделок.*{дата}.*$
```

- `^` - начало строки
- `.*` - любое число любых символов
- `\s+` - один или несколько пробелов
- `{дата}` - дата, которую нужно найти (простым текстом, экранируя точки `\.`, т.к. точка в регулярном выражении означает *любой символ*)
- `$` - конец строки

Лучше предварительно подготовить шаблон регулярного выражения, а затем его использовать. Например, в вашем случае можно подготовить его следующим образом:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd\\.MM\\.yyyy");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
    String.format("^.*реестр\\s+сделок.*%s.*$", format.format(date)),
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE
);
```

- `date` - в данном случае, текущая дата, но можно использовать любую другую
- форматирование даты с шаблоном `dd\\.MM\\.yyyy` для экранирования точек
- использование флагов `CASE_INSENSITIVE` для того, чтобы не учитывался регистр букв и `UNICODE_CASE`, чтобы правильно обрабатывались регистры букв для русского алфавита

Далее можно использовать данный шаблон в функции фильтрации:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(files)
    .filter(f -> pattern.matcher(f).matches())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: спасибо Вам большое!

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
final String sometext = "Реестр сделок";
final String regex = "(" + sometext + ".*)\\((\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4})\\)";
final String string = "Реестр сделок(03.08.2017)";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```